# Solaris 11 acpi "button" on Virtualbox

Tags: solaris

On Solaris 11 guest running in Virtualbox
linux host,i click on menu "shutdown with acpi"
but nothing happen.
On centos i had to enable acpid daemon,is there something
similar on Solaris11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't enabled anything particular and ACPI shutdown works just fine with me running VirtualBox 4.3.10 and Solaris 11.2.

Comment: If i use `shutdown -g0 -y -i5 ` works fine,but the problem is the virtual "button" or powerbutton

Comment: "ACPI Shutdown" / Control+H works here. What precise Solaris and VirtualBox releases are you using ?

Comment: Solaris 11.2 and latest virtualbox 4.3.28,now i'm upgrading to 5,i will check

Comment: ON fresh solaris 11.2 installation works,on my old solaris not

Comment: Can you better define "old solaris"? Is it an older release of Solaris, say Solaris 10 update something or a Solaris 11.2 installed some time ago?

Comment: I meant previous installation

Comment: Probably was a misconfiguration